# Can you export a list of registered users who've registered for an event via the registration module?

Tags: 7, users

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I tried to make sure it wasn't before I posted this.

In Drupal 7, does anyone know if there is "out of the box" functionality (that comes with the [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module) to export a list of people who've registered for an event via the registration module? Ideally, without using views, etc. Something that an end user/site editor could do.

I had a client ask if that were possible. I couldn't find an answer anywhere else and I've never used it before.

Comment: What do you mean by "built-in": **only** using existing facilities of either Drupal core or the registration module? Obviously, as per your "without using views, etc" you do not want to consider any other (existing) contributed module (which an end user / site editor could do) ... But guess what: "**There's a module for it**" ... (though it seems you do not want to consider that, right?). So unless you want to adapt (edit) your question, it might be tough to post an answer that could work in your case. PS: maybe PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens - Oh. Yes, my apologies. I just meant, is there a way to do it only using what comes with the registration module. I'm perfectly fine learning how to do it myself via any other means, but for a particular use case that I am faced with, I wanted to make this as simple as I could for a site editor without a lot of Drupal knowledge. Hope this helped a little. I will also edit my question. Thanks again.

Comment: ok, that's a bit clearer. Now it more looks like a "does this module have such export facility" ... right?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens - Exactly. I appreciate the feedback very much, even if it's just helping me figure out how to make a post on here. ;)  I apologize, I just don't use this as much as I probably should.

Comment: No need for "sorry", just trying to help new users on this site (so now and then). Your question is a bit clearer now and it more looks like a "does this module have such export facility" ... right? But: you still should add a correct link to your "registration" module (which has a confusing name ...) ... "I" know which one you mean, but leave it to you to also improve that part of your question ... Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-Entity-Registration-box you will (to my knowledge) not get such export facility that you are asking for, so the short answer is **NO**.

But *Sales starts when the customer says **no** ...*: have a look at the Community documentation of the [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module, especially to this part of it:

> Not happy with the default tabular list of registrations? No problem,
>   registrations and their fields are all [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) friendly. You can override the default event registrations list, create additional ones, etc.

In other words, if you're willing to accept, as a compromise, to get other modules involved, then it should be pretty forward. However with only views you still don't have the "export" function yet, and you'd need another module on top of that, like the [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module (or any of the "similar modules" mentioned on that project page).

**Unless** you're open to an alternative module for this views-and-some-other-module(s) approach ... I.e. if you'd be willing to only consider the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer), you'd have your 1 stop solution (only 1 extra module, that can do everything you are asking for). Have a look at it's community documentation to get the idea about it (or look at the answers to some of the [forena](/questions/tagged/forena) questions). Or post a followup question like "**How can I do this with the Forena module?**" (to avoid you'd have to change your question here to a *chameleon* question).

Comment: Thanks a lot. **All** of this is very helpful. It seems like there are a few ways this can be done. You're right, it seems like there is no way the Entity Registration module does this out of the box. I'm thinking that we will probably just create a custom view that we can export with [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export), but I will certainly do some research on [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena).

Comment: Thank you for "accepting" my advice .. But red flag about VDE: only a beta release ... ! Have a look at Forena before making a final choice ... (no obligation of course)